# Can't use any key after e.preventDefault() on keyDown in React

Tags: reactjs, input, event-handling, keydown, onkeydown

I need to stop users from typing more than 4 digits in an input.
Calling `e.preventDefault()` works fine with `onKeyPress`, but I don't want to use it because it's deprecated.
Using `onKeyDown` works, but after calling `e.preventDefault()`, the user can't delete the text, that input is now "frozen". I understand that it's by design. Is there a better way to stop the user from typing more than 4 digits but still to allow the deletion of the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you attempted adding the `maxLength="4"` attribute to your input?

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: Thanks, but `maxLength` doesn't work when the input's `type="number"`, only when it's `input="text"`. I'd use text and restrict the keys or use Regex, but I do need the numerical keyboard for mobile.

Comment: Solved it by changing `input="number"` to `input="text"`, adding `inputMode="numerical"`, `maxLength="4"` and defining the pattern with a regex.